# jquery scale height and width of a div from center point of screen

Tags: jquery

i am in the situation of making a customized slide show. for that, i need to make a div element and appended to body. as well i center it for the screen, using screen width and height, but i unable to make that div scale from the center point of the screen..

what i need is, which i creating div have the 0px height and 0px width, in this state, it need to scale to the size what i am going to append the image with this. so, while it get the image size ( i am keeping it in array), it need to scale height and width what array supplies. but it should start from center of the screen.

how can i achieve a div scale from center of the screen?

```
$('#slideHolder').appendTo('body').css({border:'1px solid red'});
           var getHCenter = ($(window).width() - $('#slideHolder').outerWidth())/2;
           var getVCenter = ($(window).height() - $('#slideHolder').outerHeight())/2;
           $('#slideHolder').css({left:getHCenter,top:getVCenter}).animate({height:$('#slideHolder').outerHeight()+'px',width:$('#slideHolder').outerWidth()+'px'},100).hide();
```

this is what the function what i am using.  but scale is not start and end in the center of the screen. any good idea to scale as well position the image center?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yo could proberbly use a MINUS margin instead.

```
       var getWidth = $('#slideHolder').outerWidth())/2;
       var getHeight = $('#slideHolder').outerHeight())/2;
```

And then setting on the element:

```
Left: 50%;
Top: 50%;
Margin: -getHeight 0 0 -getWidth
```

with:

```
$('#slideHolder').css('left':'50%','top':'50%','margin':'-'+getHeight+' 0 0 -'getWidth);
```

What it does is send it 50% from the left and top, and then giving the minus margin half of #slideHolder - making it centered from the top and left :)

**EDIT**

Guess this is what you want?

http://jsfiddle.net/V5KLa/

Comment: You are correct, but your information can usable on static situational. how can we use this for animate purpose?, because i need to scale from 0 to 100 right?

Comment: But your animation dosent make much sense.. You dont change height and with, yet you animate them. And you hide your box after animation?

Comment: Animation are working properly. but in case if the width and height is not same, then it makes issue. it only works on square boxes. Other wise the positions get varies. Andy idea for all shapes?